# How to flash color change for text inside a div element with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to flash the color change of gender and comment(flash them red and turn back to original again)

```
  var dataDIV = $("<div id="+dataDivId+" class=\"data\"></div>");
  $("#data").append(dataDIV);
  var divData= $(
   "<h3 class=\"name\">"+person.name+"</h3>"+
   "<h2 class=\"gender\">"+person.gender+"</h2>"+
   "<p class=\"comment\">("+person.comment+")</p>"
   );   
  $("#"+dataDivId).html(divData);
```

I tried to do it with:

```
 $(divData).effect("highlight", {color:"#FF0000"}, 1500);
```

But it would apply flash effect on the entire divData, not the h2 and p elements. Is there any way I can do it just for gender and comment?

I also don't want this to happen to other div units that have this divData element in it(not flashing other person objects, just the one being changed)

I tried to pull out ""+person.gender+"" as a separate variable and apply effect to it, that didn't work either.

Comment: Making it work on just the h2 and p elements is easy, but what do you mean by "not flashing other person objects, just the one being changed"?

Comment: like if i update gender and comment information of one person, and i have multiple person divs on the page, I want to hightlight the changed one only. That's just to say we can't just select all h2 elements on the page with gender in it and apply hightlight.

Comment: So how do you delineate the person being changed from everyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need something like below,

```
$('.gender, .comment', $('#' + dataDivId)).effect("highlight", {
   color: "#FF0000"
}, 1500);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kG8qJ/4/) Click on Add button.

Comment: It looks solid for the selector part(flashing the right stuff), thanks a lot. Do you think I can change the text color instead of flashing the container of text through $.effect(highlight)?

Comment: @ttback Try http://jsfiddle.net/kG8qJ/5/ and Also you can try `.animate ({css: '#ff0000'}, 1500)`

Comment: Thanks. Tried the css tag yesterday and it worked like charms. Didn't know animate supports it too. Thank you very much.